# React-router 2.0 browserHistory doesn't work when refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

Below codes report 404 not found when refreshing on page http://localhost/about. But if browserHistory is changed to hashHistory, it works fine.

Here are my js file.

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink, browserHistory, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import $ from 'jquery';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>APP!</h1>
        <Link to="/about">/about</Link>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>About 33</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

var routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/wealth" component={WealthExpectation} />
    </Router>
)

$(document).ready(function() {ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("hello"))});
```

And the html file.

```jsx
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello React</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
        <!-- build:css -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bower_modules/c3/c3.min.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hello">a</div>
        <div id="world"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've read the questions on [react-router v2.0 browserHistory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937448/react-router-v2-0-browserhistory-not-working) and [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually). For the first one, I've already set the path to absolute path, but still not working. For the second one, I tried to import express but failed ('Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined').

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: I tried to import express 4, but reported 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined'

Comment: I don't get it, are you handling your routes with express?

Comment: No, not now. I tried several days ago, but failed, so I removed the related codes.

Comment: using browser history you need to implement /about in your backend, you can use express to do that : var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
}); app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

Comment: But when I tried to import express, it reports error. I searched the error, and found express-session should be used. But I can't find a whole example of how to use express-session.

Answer (score 29):

To expand on Phi Nguyen's answer the reason hashHistory works and browserHistory fails is because hashHistory is sort of a 'hack' or workaround to allow your app to manipulate the URL without the browser noticing and sending a `GET` request to your server. Essentially everything after the Hash is ignored.

browserHistory is generally preferred because it looks better but you no longer get the hash workaround and you need other means of preventing your browser from trying to send requests to your server. IF you are using webpack there is a simple way to essentially make all requests fallback to a single request. For example:

`GET` to http://localhost:8080/ AND a `GET` to http://localhost:8080/about would both fallback to http://localhost:8080/ and react-router would deal with the /about. (this is the reason you are able to navigate to /about fine, but if you refresh you get a `404` error, you're sending a `GET` to /about which doesn't exist on your server)

To do this you need to implement a webpack feature called history api fallback. There's two ways of doing that.

From the react-router docs / tutorial you can setup your `start` script to look like this:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base . --history-api-fallback"
```

Where the --history-api-fallback is the important piece for anyone with this error.

OR you can change your `webpack.config.js` file to look handle this on your dev server.

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    ...other stuff..
  },
```

Comment: It will work perfectly along with that steps,
`devServer: {
    historyApiFallback:{
        index:'./index.html'
    },`

Comment: So this is setup on the webpack dev server, which is typically only used for development. In production would you still need to configure this on whatever server hosts your code?

Comment: "you need other means of preventing your browser from trying to send requests to your server"

Is that correct? I think the browser sends the request when refreshing. It is not about preventing but about handling the request on the server side.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative, simple and low-cost approach is to make Apache map any request to your React app. For example: `http://localhost/about` goes internally thru `http://localhost/[my-own-html-file.html]`

For example, if our React app starts at `index.html`, you need to create a `.htaccess` file on your React app and insert the following code:

```
# Map all non-existing URLs to be processed by index.html,
# so any URL that doesn't point to a JS file, CSS file, etc etc...
# goes through my React app.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

BTW, this HTACCESS code was adapted from Drupal 8:
https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.2.x/.htaccess

Answer (score 3):

if you are using netlify to deploy your site you can create a file **_redirects** to you public directory and add a simple line in it

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

index.html is just a file which you are using in the public folder like this example

[image]

> _redirect file

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you use `browser history`,  the server doesn't know how to handle the URL which is changed in the browser only.
This [tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls) will teach you how to remove `#` in url and make `browser history` work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use browserHistory you need to implement an express server to handle real URLs. hashHistory doesn't need an express server.

Have a look on the following guide:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Answer (score 1):

I've got URL workings by adding this line to the NGINX server block

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
```

Server gives you a 404 because the /about  doesn't exit. You have to force every request thru the index file of your build so that the Router component can pick up on the /about and load the page properly.